# Is this graph connected or path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I was thinking about a map *f* such that $Graph(f)$ is connected but it is not path connected, this is the map:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl} \sqrt{x^2-1} &\ x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
-\sqrt{x^2-1} &\ x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}
 \end{array}\right.$$

It is clear that it is not path connected in each segment that connects two points there are rational and irrational numbers, so my question is:

It is connected?

Comment: Suggestion: Is $\mathbf{Q}$ connected?

Comment: No it isn't , for example $(-\infty,π),( π,\infty)$.

Comment: So...does that answer your question? (If so, it's fine to post your own answer!)

Comment: Of vourse hahaha , thank you , i will try to formalize an answer

Answer (score 1):

it is not connected because it can be represented  as the union of two disjoint non-empty  open sets:

$$A := (-2,2) \times \left(-2,\sqrt{1-\frac{\pi^2}{4^2}}\right)$$

$$B := (-2,2) \times \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{\pi^2}{4^2}},2\right)$$

As $A \cap B = \varnothing$ and $ Graph(f) \subset A \cup B$ so it is not connected.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable until you decide what the codomain is. (As defined, $f$ is not real-valued.) Whatever you use, the A and B in your answer are not a partition of the graph, even if you restrict the domain to (-2,2). They contain many points not on the graph, and do not contain $(\pi/4,f(\pi/4))$.

Comment: Thank you for the support now I think it is correct

Comment: The graph - even with domain (-2,2) - still doesn't fit into $A \cup B$. You're missing the parts where $f(x)$ is not real.